# Generating HTML reports using Apache ANT on Distributed Load Testing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

Can any one please help me on this.?

I want to do a distributed load testing using Jmeter 2.11. For getting detailed and meaningful reports, I Integrated Jmeter with Apache Ant. I tried running the test from 'cmd' and the test is only running locally and generating reports..!! I have remote servers specified inside Jmeter.properties file.

Is Ant not able to take the Jmeter.properties.? Do I have to add anything in build.xml file.?

Please advise..

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter Ant Task documentation](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)

> Optional JMeter arguments supported include specifying an alternate jmeter properties file (jmeterproperties), running remote servers specified in jmeter properties file (**runremote**)

So you need to apply `runremote="true" parameter to properties you need to pass to slave machines.

A couple of other recommendations:

1. Upgrade to the [latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (currently it's 2.13), newer versions contain new features, bug fixes, performance improvements, etc. See [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide for more tweaks.
2. It is not necessary to run JMeter via Ant. If you switch JMeter output format to XML (add `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` line to *user.properties* files on all nodes) and run JMeter as normal according to [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) guide you'll be able to use `ant report` task on resulting file to generate HTML output. Moreover, any tool which can do XSLT transformation can generate HTML report. Required .xsl files are under /extras dir of your JMeter installation.